# How to disable javamail SSL support?

Tags: java, ssl, seam, jakarta-mail

I receive the following Exception while trying to send an email (using Seam)

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find vali
d certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:285)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:191)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1014)
        ... 68 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:280)
        ... 74 more
```

I tested the server by using a plain javamail app with no extra settings and it worked fine.

But using Seams mail-tags the Exception occurs. 
- Is there a way to disable SSL? 
I realy don't need SSL.

I found these properties in a [forum](http://www.apacheserver.net/JAVA-CLIENT-10-08-31-20-27-54-INFO-ipc-HbaseRPC-Problem-at233888.htm)

```
mail.smtp.ssl.trust="*"
mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
```

- How could I pass them the properties above through seam framework down to javamail ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Seam reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/en-US/html/components.html#components.mail) and [Seam forum](http://seamframework.org/Community/SeamMailSSLCacertorg#comment15433) you should be able to disable TLS and SSL directly in your `components.xml` configuration:

```
<mail:mail-session debug="true" tls="false" ssl="false" ... />
```

Answer (score 4):

The error you're getting means that one of the certificates (presumably the server's certificate) isn't trusted by your JavaMail client. Since you seem to be using STARTTLS, you're effectively using SSL/TLS.

You could perhaps try something like `mail.smtp.starttls.enable="false"` if you don't want to use SSL/TLS at all, although some SMTP servers will force you to use it (either SSL/TLS on connection or via STARTTLS) to proceed any further.

Alternatively, if you change your mind and want/need to use SSL, make sure your trust store on the client side contains a trust anchor (CA certificate) that can be used to verify your server certificate. (Note that the `mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity` default to `false` is insecure, so you'd want to change that to `true`, and not use `mail.smtp.ssl.trust="*"`.)

Comment: (+1) sorry I aimed for something else sorry if I failed to express this correctly.