# How to set properties in a Seam component before @create?

Tags: java, seam, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to set the following members of Component `org.jboss.seam.mail.mailSession` which are defined as:

```
boolean ssl;
boolean tls = true;
```

(both have getter and setter methods)
before the method create which is annotated with @Create is called .
I want to prevent the framework to use SSL,TLS. The mailSession component checks whether these mebers are set. If yes it creates properties which force javamail to use ssl.

I tried so far:

```
Object comp = Component.getInstance("org.jboss.seam.mail.mailSession");
```

**Problem**: unwraps to javax.mail.Session where I can't access the component.

```
Object comp = Component.getInstance("org.jboss.seam.mail.mailSession", ScopeType.APPLICATION,false,false);
```

**Problem**: returns null since no instance is created.

```
Component comp = Component.forName("org.jboss.seam.mail.mailSession");
```

**Problem**: A component and not the instance is returned.

What should I do to toggle 2 bits, would you recommend to patch the framework, or is there an easier way I've overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to override the mailSession?
I am not sure if it works though...

Something along the lines of

```
@Name("org.jboss.seam.mail.mailSession")
@Install(precedence=Application)
class MyMailSession extends MailSession {

  //override the stuff you want here
}
```

Comment: +1 That should work because the precedence of `Application` is higher than `BUILT_IN`; meaning that `MyMailSession` will be installed instead of `MailSession`.

Comment: Thanks for this insightful approach, it is more generic and I guess I will need it sometime.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Seam reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/en-US/html/components.html#components.mail) and [Seam forum](http://seamframework.org/Community/SeamMailSSLCacertorg#comment15433) you should be able to disable TLS and SSL directly in your `components.xml` configuration:

```
<mail:mail-session debug="true" tls="false" ssl="false" ... />
```

Have you already tried that?

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm . Would you please copy your answer to this question I asked, which is more specific http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237970/how-to-disable-javamail-ssl-support (I will accept it of course)

Comment: @stacker Of course, I copied it. I'm glad I could have helped.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using this sequence:

```
@In(create = true)
private Renderer renderer;
...
Component comp = Component.forName("org.jboss.seam.mail.mailSession");
MailSession ms = (MailSession)  comp.newInstance();
ms.setDebug(true);
ms.setTls(false);
ms.setSsl(false);
ms = ms.create();

renderer.render("/Mail.xhtml");
```

I wonder how the MailSession instance is attached to the component, but for now it works.